# Can a LP created on a Windows platform be run on a Linux platform?

Tags: python, linux, windows, matlab, gurobi

I have a huge MILP in Matlab, which I want to re-program in Gurobi using python language, on a Windows desktop. But after that I want to run it on a super computer which has a Linux os. I know python is cross-platform. Does this mean anything I create in Gurobi on Windows will run on Linux too? If this question is dumb I'm sorry, I just want to know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write Gurobi Python code on one system, then copy it and run it on another. You can go from Windows to Linux, Mac to Windows, etc.  Alternately, if you have Gurobi Compute Server, your Windows computer can be a client of your Linux server.

Answer (score 0):

You could also export the MILP from Matlab as a [mps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPS_(format)) file, using e.g. the [MPS format exporting tool](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19618-mps-format-exporting-tool) and then load the file to Gurobi on the system of your choice.

Comment: Thanks @JaBe. The MPS format exporting tool says 'Only single rhs (b and beq) is supported.' Does this mean my rhs has to be a scalar, cannot be a vector? :(

Comment: @user3579897 I think that single rhs means that you can not have left hand side (lhs) arguments in your constraints. In the [comments of the tool](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19618-mps-format-exporting-tool/content/BuildMPS/BuildMPS.m) it is clearly stated, that rhs can be vectors.